# Running java jars under linux

Tags: java, linux, jar

I created a jar file and want to run it on linux machine.
In win32 machine I'm using: 
java -classpath myclass.jar;log4j-1.2.16.jar;mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar;. com.name.myClass.MyClass
However, on linux its doesn't work? Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: have you tried using the absolute paths on the library names?

Comment: Linux uses colon as a path separator, but Windows uses semi-colon. Have a look at the PATH environment variable on both systems to see the impact of that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use : instead of ; to separate items in your classpath:

```
-classpath myclass.jar:log4j-1.2.16.jar:mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar:.
```